# How to bridge two LAN segments through serial port using Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, bridge, serial-port

I have an application where two subnets are bridged transparently through two [Serial to Ethernet Bridges](https://www.dcbnet.com/datasheet/etherbridge.html) and a null modem serial cable (RS-232, TX and RX only). This setup behaves exactly as an Ethernet cable, except for the speed and latency.

[image: My application diagram]

These bridges are pretty expensive for me and I was wondering how to do it with a cheap SBC running Linux (e.g. Raspberry Pi). I've been searching for days with no success.

I've read on forums that netcat, ppp and ser2net will not do the job, and brctl only works for Ethernet interfaces. I though about using socat or bridge-utils but I could not find any reference of an application similar to mine. I saw tons of applications where a serial device is bridged over a TCP connection, not the inverse which is my case.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

My network knowledge is basic and I apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: You may not need to bridge the connections to do what you want.  Assuming the networks are in different subnets, and assuming neither is the router on its network, you could create routing rules to send traffic for that subnet to your "Serial A" and "Serial B" machines on the respective networks.  (I assume for some odd reason you *must* do this by serial ports, although almost any other means of networking is going to do a better job in terms of speed.)

Comment: Yes, since you begin with "**two** subnets", it is more likely that you want routing and not bridging. A bridge would result in one subnet... Besides, routing IP over serial is much more common (simple pppd) than bridging Ethernet over serial.

Comment: Hi @Jim MacKenzie. Yes! There are odd reasons so I _must_ use serial ports. I didn't make it clear on my question. The best scenario for me is the one where each branch can "see" the other as part of the same subnet, not two separate ones, that's why I asked about bridging. However, If the routing approach works, it will be great. I didn't know that I could do it using pppd, I thought it would only work between two computers.
I'll get my hardware back in a few days so I'll be able to try it.

Comment: Hi @grawity, the comment above is for you too.

Comment: @rcm: Any specific reason for a single subnet? What exactly do you mean by "see" here?

Comment: Because the original application works this way and changing the existing Serial to Ethernet Bridges for new ones will produce a lower impact. All IPs on both sides are fixed and in the range 10.10.1.1/28 to 10.10.1.14/28.
I will try your PPP suggestion too, I still must figure out how to route the packets.

Answer (score 1):

Quickshot with `socat`, untested:

```
socat TUN:10.10.1.4/24,tun-type=tap,tun-name=tap0,iff-up /dev/ttyS0,rawer
```

Then add it to the bridge (say, `br0`):

```
ip link set tap0 master br0
```

May need some modifications if `rawer` is still not raw enough. IIRC it only needs the IP address to make `socat` happy.

Alternatively, use some protocol that's made for networking over a serial link, like SLIP or PPP, and that will properly escape funny characters and do flow control in a pinch, and then run a layer 2 tunnel over it. Less efficient and more difficult to set up.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, I'll get my hardware back in a few days so I'll be able to try it. Thank you.

Comment: @rcm Well?  How did it go?